# deriving antiprism formulas

Tags: geometry, derivation-of-formulae

According to Wikipedia:

Let $a$ be the edge-length of a uniform $n$-gonal antiprism; then the volume is:

$$V = \frac{n \sqrt{4\cos^2\frac{\pi}{2n}-1}\sin \frac{3\pi}{2n} }{12\sin^2\frac{\pi}{n}}~a^3$$

and the surface area is:

$$A = \frac{n}{2} \left( \cot\frac{\pi}{n} + \sqrt{3} \right) a^2$$

Furthermore, the volume of a right $n$-gonal antiprism with side length of its bases $l$ and height $h$ is given by:

$$V = \frac{nhl^2}{12} \left( \csc\frac{\pi}{n} + 2\cot\frac{\pi}{n}\right).$$

Does anyone know how these formulas are derived?  I always prefer to understand where a formula comes from rather than taking Wikipedia's word for it.  Pictures are always appreciated.

Bonus: I would also like to know the surface area and volume formulae for crossed and twisted antiprisms and their derivations, if anyone knows them.

Comment: Surely you can derive the surface area for yourself at the very least--it should be accessible to anyone who has studied trigonometry.  Also, try deriving the general volume formula (third equation) first, then set $l = a$ and choose an appropriate $h$ in terms of $a$ such that the sides are equilateral triangles.

Comment: Did you check [Wofram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Antiprism.html)?

Comment: You posted this the other day, and then deleted it? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4846854/what-is-the-general-formula-for-the-volume-of-an-antiprism-whose-bases-are-regul

Comment: ^Yes, because I found the formulas on wikipedia and this is a better question.

Answer (score 2):

Antiprisms belong to a class of polyhedron known as [prismatoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prismatoid). To compute the volume of a prismatoid, one only need $4$ numbers: its altitude and three areas.

> A prismatoid is a polyhedron whose vertices lies on two parallel planes and the side faces (faces not on the two planes) are either triangles or trapezoids.

Given a prismatoid, the distance between the two parallel planes is known as its altitude (or height). Let's denote it by $h$.

Choose a coordinate system where the two planes are $z = 0$ and $z = h$. Let $q$ be the number of side edges (edges not on the two planes). If one intersect the prismatoid with plane $z = t$ for a $t \in (0,h)$, the intersection will be a $q$-gon.

Let $\Delta(t)$ be the area of the $q$-gon and $(x_i(t),y_i(t),t)$ be the coordinates of the intersection between the $i^{th}$ side edge and plane $z = t$. Assume the side edges are ordered correctly, $\Delta(t)$ can be computed using [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula):
$$\Delta(t) = \frac12\sum_{i=1}^q (x_i(t) y_{i+1}(t) - y_i(t)x_{i+1}(t))$$

Since the side edges are straight lines, $x_i(t), y_i(t)$ are polynomial in $t$ with degree at most $1$. So $\Delta(t)$ is a
polynomial in $t$ with degree at most $2$.

The volume of the prismatoid can be expressed as an integral.

$$\verb/Volume/ = \int_0^h \Delta(t) dt$$
Being a polynomial with degree at most $2$, above integral of $\Delta(t)$ can be evaluated exactly using  [Simpson's 1/3 rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule#Simpson%27s_1/3_rule). The end result is
the

> **prismoidal formula**
> $$\verb/Volume/ = \frac{h}{6}\left(\Delta_{t} + 4\Delta_{m} + \Delta_{b}\right)
> $$ where
> $\Delta_t = \Delta(h)$, $\Delta_m = \Delta(\frac{h}{2})$, $\Delta_b = \Delta(0)$ are the areas of the "top" face, the "middle" cross-section and "bottom" face of the prismatoid respectively.

Let's apply this to an antiprism $X_0$ whose top/bottom faces are regular $n$-gon with side $\ell$ and altitude $h$.

Let $\alpha_n$ be the area of a regular $n$-gon with side $1$.
Since we can decompose such a $n$-gon into $n$ triangles with
base $1$ and height $\frac12\cot\frac{\pi}{n}$, we have
$$\alpha_n = \frac{n}{4}\cot\frac{\pi}{n}$$
So $\Delta_t = \Delta_b = \alpha_n \ell^2$. It is not hard to see the middle cross-section of the antiprism is a regular $2n$-gon with side $\frac{\ell}{2}$. This means $\Delta_m = \frac14 \alpha_{2n} \ell^2$.
Plug these into prismoidal formula, one obtain the formula for volume of antiprism you want to derive

$$\verb/Volume/(X_0) = \frac{h\ell^2}{6}\left(2\alpha_n + \alpha_{2n}\right)
= \frac{nh\ell^2}{12}\left(\cot\frac{\pi}{n} + \cot\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)
= \frac{nh\ell^2}{12}\left(2\cot\frac{\pi}{n} + \csc\frac{\pi}{n}\right)
$$
For the uniform $n$-gonal antiprism with side $a$, $\ell = a$ and one only need to figure out what $h$ is. If one project its vertices to $xy$-plane, the vertices will form a regular $2n$-gon with circumradius $\frac{a}{2}\csc\frac{\pi}{n}$.
The side edges of antiprism get projected to line segments
of length $\displaystyle\;s = \frac{2a\sin\frac{\pi}{2n}}{2\sin\frac{\pi}{n}} 
= \frac{a}{2\cos\frac{\pi}{2n}}\;$. This leads to
$$h = \sqrt{a^2 - s^2} = \frac{a}{2\cos\frac{\pi}{2n}}\sqrt{4\cos^2\frac{\pi}{2n} - 1}$$
As a result, the volume of regular $n$-gonal antiprism is

$$V = \frac{na^3}{24}\sqrt{4\cos^2\frac{\pi}{2n} - 1}\underbrace{\frac{\cot\frac{\pi}{n} + \cot\frac{\pi}{2n}}{\cos\frac{\pi}{2n}}}_{\color{blue}{[1]}}
= \frac{na^3\sqrt{4\cos^2\frac{\pi}{2n} - 1}\sin\frac{3\pi}{2n}}{12\sin^2\frac{\pi}{n}}
$$
Aside from a typo in your original formula, this is what you already know.

About its area, it is simply

$$(2\alpha_n + 2n\alpha_3)a^2
= a^2 \left(2\frac{n}{4}\cot\frac{\pi}{n} + 2n\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)
= \frac{na^2}{2}\left(\cot\frac{\pi}{n} + \sqrt{3}\right)$$

**Update** - about volume of twisted prisms.

Start with antiprism $X_0$ we have studied before. Let $R = \frac{\ell}{2\sin\frac{\pi}{n}}$. WOLOG, we will assume in cylindrical polar coordinates${}^{\color{blue}{[2]}}$, the vertices of $X_0$ are located at

$$ (\rho,\theta,z) = (R, \frac{2k\pi}{n}, h), (R,\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{n},0)
\quad\text{ for }\quad k = 0, \ldots, n-1$$

If one twist the top face by an angle $\phi$, ie. replace vertices $(R,\frac{2k\pi}{n},h)$ by $(R,\phi + \frac{2k\pi}{n},h)$ while keep vertices at bottom face fixed, we obtain a twisted prism. Let's call it $X_\phi$. When $|\phi| < \frac{\pi(n-1)}{n}$, this twisted prism is an ordinary polyhedron and prismoidal formula applies.

Let $\phi_{\pm} = \frac12(\phi \pm \frac{\pi}{n})$. The mid-section is a star-shaped $2n$-gon with vertices located at

$$(\rho,\theta,z) = 
(R\cos\phi_{-}, \phi_{-} + \frac{2k\pi}{n}, \frac{h}{2}),
(R\cos\phi_{+}, \phi_{+} + \frac{2k\pi}{n}, \frac{h}{2}),
\quad\text{ for }\quad k = 0, \ldots, n - 1$$

It has area
$$\Delta_m = \frac{2n}{2} (R\cos\phi_{+})(R\cos\phi_{-})\sin\frac{\pi}{n}
= \frac{n\ell^2}{8\sin\frac{\pi}{n}}(\cos\frac{\pi}{n} + \cos\phi)$$

Plug these into prismoidal formula,
the volume of twisted prism $X_\phi$ is given by the formula:
$$\bbox[border:1px solid blue;padding: 1em;]{
\verb/Volume/(X_\phi) = \frac{nh\ell^2}{12}\left(2\cot\frac{\pi}{n} + \csc\frac{\pi}{n}\cos\phi\right)}$$

In particular, when $\phi = \pm \frac{\pi}{n}$, $X_\phi$ reduces to a $n$-gonal prism. Above expression reproduces the volume $\alpha_n h\ell^2$.

When $|\phi| \ge \frac{\pi(n-1)}{n}$, I haven't figure out what the twisted prism becomes. It is probably too complicated for me and I'll stop here.

**Notes**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ - let $c = \cos\frac{\pi}{2n}$ and $s = \sin\frac{\pi}{2n}$, the mess can be simplified to
  $$\frac{\frac{c^2-s^2}{2sc} + \frac{c}{s}}{c} = 2 \frac{(4c^2-1)s}{(2cs)^2} = 2\frac{\sin\frac{3\pi}{2n}}{\sin^2\frac{\pi}{n}}$$
- $\color{blue}{[2]}$ - In terms of $(\rho,\theta,z)$, Cartesian coordinates $(x,y,z) = ( \rho\cos\theta, \rho\sin\theta, z)$.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This will probably get the bounty in 2 days.  Is calculus required for certain parts or is it possible to derive everything without calculus?

Comment: @John it is possible to derive the volume w/o any calculus by 1) calculate coordinates of vertices, 2) decompose antiprism into a bunch of tetrahedra 3) calculate volume of a tetrahedron as 1/6 times a determinant in the coordinates. However, if you step back and ask where the factor 1/6 = 1/2 x 1/3 comes from. The 1/2 factor comes from area of a triangle is 1/2 of corr. parallelogram, the 1/3 comes from volume of a pyramid is 1/3 of corr. prism. This is really a disguise of the fact $\int_0^1 x^2 dx = \frac13$. If you get  rid of calculus, then you need to deal with those mysterious factors.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to think about is a coordinatisation of its vertices, such as
$(\frac{\cos(k π/n)}{2\sin(π/n)}, \frac{\sin(k π/n)}{2\sin(π/n)}, (-1)^k \frac{h}2)$  for all $k$ integral. (Here the denominators of the first two coordinates just ensure unit side lengths of the base polygons.) Then observe the body center in here is the origin. Accordingly the volume easily gets calculated by the sum of volumes of face-based pyramids pointing (with their tips) each to that body center.

In order to do so, because the volume of a pyramid is $\frac13 hG$, where h is *its* height and G is the base area, i.e. the area of the according polygon, you surely will have to evaluate those beforehand. But these are either geometrically straight forward, or can in turn be calculated by the same approach one dimension lower: take the center point of each face and calculate the "volume" (= area) of all its "face"-based (= side-based) "pyramids" (= triangles).

Those individual face areas clearly have to be summed up only, when asking for the total surface content.

Finally, note that three consecutive vertices of the coordinates of the first paragraph (i.e. with consecutive $k$) will enclose a lateral triangle of that antiprism. If that one would be asked to become a *regular* triangle, this imposes a restriction onto $h$, which can be solved for and thus inserted into your latter volume formula (i.e. Volume($n,l,h$)) becoming the volume formula of the uniform antiprism as of your first volume formula (i.e. Volume($n, a$), where $a\equiv l$ for sure).

--- rk